# TCP recover connection after hardware disconnect

Tags: sockets, tcp, broken-pipe, connection-reset

I've got a program that continuously writes to a TCP socket. I want to make sure that if the connection between the client and server is disconnected for any amount of time, the connection can be restablished.

Right now, I can disconnect the wire, and while the write() function loops, it returns one "connection reset by peer" error, and then the value of ULLONG_MAX. Then, once I replug the wire, write() continuously returns "broken pipe" errors. I've tried to close and reopen the connection but I continue to get the "connection reset by peer" error.

Does anyone know how I could either restablish the connection or keep it alive for a certain amount of time (or indefinitely) in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot re-use file descriptor here, you have to start from scratch again - create new [`socket(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) and call [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to establish a new connection, and that can only initiated by the client program. You might need some way to ensure it's the same client reconnecting maybe check the IP or exchange a token on first connection, so you can do some different kind of initiation on your connection for first connection and recovery. That solution needs some programming on your account, though..

If TCP is not for some reason the only choice, you might want to think about UDP communication, since there the part that decideds when a connection is lost is left to you. But you'll need to take care of a lot of other thinks (but since you are aiming for a lost and recover communication, that might be more to your needs).